# Comparing two complex objects, one from DB and one from input

Tags: c#, linq, compare

I have a program that takes in a file, does some data crunching and then compares the result with what is in the DB.

**Object**

```
public class ReleaseDates
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MovieName { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string AlternateSource { get; set; }
}
```

It is very likely that the `MovieName` will be the same as what is in the DB but the `ReleaseDate` could change.

How can I compare what I grab from the DB to a `ReleaseDate` object list?

**Example**

```
public bool Compare(ReleaseDates original, ReleaseDates newObj)
    {
        if (original.AlternateSource != newDate.AlternateSource)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (original.Country != newDate.Country)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (original.MovieName != newDate.MovieName)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (original.ReleaseDate != newDate.ReleaseDate)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

How I am getting the data from the DB:

```
public List<ReleaseDates> GetAllReleaseDates()
{
    return Db.ReleaseDates.ToList(); // Db is my DataContext
}
```

The above example is to compare for a single instance of `ReleaseDates`, but how can I compare a list? I cannot order the List since there will be duplicates with the same `MovieName` but different `ReleaseDate` and `AlternateSource`.

**Update**
Sorry I have asked the wrong question.

What I want to do is compare the DB list with the new list and if they are different, remove it from the DB and insert the new item.

E.g.

```
public void Example(ReleaseDates A, ReleaseDates B)
{
    if(A.MovieName != B.MovieName) // But need to compare all properties
    {
        Db.ReleaseDates.Remove(A);
        Db.ReleaseDates.Add(B);
        Db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: show the code where you fetch data from db

Comment: I would recommend you to rename the method to Equals. Compare usually returns an int and is used for sorting. See documentation String.Compare for example.
Comparing two lists depends on your needs. Is the order of the items important?

Comment: You might also want to check your objects for null.

Comment: What is the required result of the comparision: a bool indication both lists are equal or a list with objects that are the same or are equal?

Comment: I am sorry, I have slightly asked the wrong question. I am going to close this and re-try.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I have asked the wrong type of question. What I asked is not what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool Compare(List<ReleaseDates> A, List<ReleaseDates> B)
{
    if ( A.Count != B.Count ) return false;
    foreach (ReleaseDates aElement in A)
    {
        if ( !B.Any ( bElement => Compare( aElement, bElement  ) return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This assumes ordering doesn't matter, but each element in the list must have an equivalent item in the other list.  It would perform better if these were all ordered by something and you could compare items at maching indexes.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you treat your collections as sets. You can override the equals method of ReleaseDates class (I feel Movie is a better name for this class) and add the elements of each collection to a HashSet.

You can use HashSet.SetEquals method to check for equality.